# Linkage of function declared as `extern` in block scope according to the C++17 standard draft

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, iso, c++17, linkage

From the [C++17 Standard Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) `§ 3.5.6`:

> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope extern
>   declaration have linkage. *If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the same name and
>   type*, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, *the block scope declaration
>   declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such
>   matching entity, the program is ill-formed*. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity
>   receives external linkage

Additionally there is an example provided in the standard:

```
static void f();
static int i = 0;              // #1
void g() {
    extern void f();          // internal linkage
    int i;                    // #2 i has no linkage
    {
        extern void f();      // internal linkage
        extern int i;         // #3 external linkage
    }
}
```

Does the third function declaration `extern void f()` receives:

- `external` linkage ( due to the preceding `extern void f()` declaration )
- `internal` linkage ( since the second declaration of `f()` in the block scope above receives internal linkage from the declaration of `f()`in the `::` global namespace )
- Or is it ill-formed because there are more " more than one such matching
  entity" ?

---

**EDIT**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern void g();
void f() { std::cout << "main f() called" << std::endl; }

int main(){
    g(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**test.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

static void f() { std::cout << " test f() called" << std::endl; }
void g() {
    extern void f(); 
    {
        extern void f(); 
        f(); 
    }
}
```

`g()` is called in the `main()` function in `main.cpp`.
Compiled with `gcc 5.4.0`

> g++ -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp test.cpp

Prints:

> main f() called

Thus, gcc obviously treats the call of `f()` from within `g()` with `external` linkage ( calling the definition provided in the `main.cpp` file ). Either the comment in the example from the standard is wrong ( the function declaration of `#3` has not interal linkage ) or its a compiler bug from `gcc`.

Comment: "Ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing **namespace** scope". The key word is "namespace". All the identifiers in the example are in the same namespace.

Comment: @AlexP why does the variable `i` from `#3` then have `external` linkage and not `static` linkage as declared in `#1` ?

Comment: "There are three objects named _i_ in this program.  The object with internal linkage introduced by the declaration in global scope (line #1), the object with automatic storage duration and no linkage introduced by the declaration on line #2, and the object with static storage duration and external linkage introduced by the declaration on line #3." See §3.5.9 why `extern int i` is not the same _i_ as `static int i`.

Comment: @AlexP Ah okay, I see. Kind of tricky. Thus all three `i`'s denote to three different variables and all `f()`'s denote to the same function ? Compiling it with `g++ 5.4.0` provides a correct behavior for the variables but the call to the function `f()` above `#3` calls the definition provided in an other translation unit. Is it a bug from `gcc` or did the definition change in the recent draft ?

Comment: @SebTu: the definition was already the same in Draft n3337 for C++11

Comment: How can you call g if it isn't declared in main.cpp? Show us the entire code, I can't adjust my answer otherwise.

Comment: @Columbo done. The behavior should be reproducible now, with the code provided above.

Comment: Okay, this actually seems to be a bug, but just to be safe, can you test that with another implementation?

Comment: This is [CWG1839](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1839); the current (unpublished) plan for it is that the `extern int i;` get *internal* linkage instead and not be an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your confusion. The innermost enclosing namespace scope is that of the [global namespace](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.namespace#3); the first and second declarations match in type and name, and hence the outer block-scope declaration just inherits the global declaration's linkage (which is internal due to the `static` specifier). The second block-scope declaration is associated with the first one; you get the idea.