# Why same named extern local variables in different blocks get different linkages between compilers in c++?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, extern, linkage

While I was just checking which linkages are granted to extern local variables
I found that some different behavior between compilers

for instance if I tested below code
as you see in the comments variable `var`s have different linkages

```cpp
// foo.cpp
int var = 10;                // external linkage

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

static int var = 100;        // internal linkage

int main() {
    extern int var;          // internal linkage
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    {
        extern int var;      // g++: external linkage , clang++: internal linkage
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
        {
            extern int var;  // g++: external linkage , clang++: internal linkage
            std::cout << var << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

the result is

- g++ : "100 10 10"
- clang++, msvc++ : "100 100 100"

I can see from the result that if there are more than two nested blocks
g++ just grants external linkages to variables

I could find related phrase in the standard
but it is still unclear because its behavior is different by compilers
(https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#6)

I'm afraid that my English is bad so I can't get it correctly
If someone have an idea that which compilers are conforming the standard well
and if possible could someone elaborate what the standard says exactly for me?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978949/linkage-of-function-declared-as-extern-in-block-scope-according-to-the-c17-s I believe it's a gcc bug, standard gives the example with `f()` function and the innermost `extern void f()` has internal linkage - `var` should have internal linkage here too, because it refers to the same "entity".

Comment: IMO block scope declarations of entities with external linkage are Evil and the language would be better off with banning them

Comment: @M.M: Module units do so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the subject of the open issue [CWG1839](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1839).  The current *intent* is that the behavior of Clang and MSVC is correct.